# Node/JS Inline Variable Values

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am interested in retrieving the values of variables in code as or after it has run. There are only a few applications that I know of that do this.

The Chrome DevTools: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/07/07/preview-javascript-values-inline-while-debugging?hl=en

And also Wallabyjs: https://github.com/wallabyjs/public

How is this accomplished? Is there an existing NPM package to do this?

Comment: I think node-inspector is what you looking for.

Comment: @MinusFour No, I know perfectly well how to debug applications. I am looking for insight into how variables are extracted from a running program in memory and if there is an API to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a founder and core developer of wallaby.js, so can definitely answer the second part, but will try to answer both.

Re: Chrome DevTools: You may retrieve the data you're after from V8 using [Remote debugging protocol](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/debugger-protocol). That's how WebStorm and some other integrations work.

Re: Wallaby.js: We instrument the code before its execution (for the purpose of providing the code coverage), and replacing some function calls (such as `console.log(obj)`) with a call to our API: `tracer.log(obj)`. In the `tracer.log` we just dump the object by traversing its properties reasonable number of level deep, similar to [how node.js console.log does it](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/7d14dd9b5e78faabb95d454a79faa513d0bbc2a5/lib/util.js#L195).